# Программа для создания графов

Tags: графы

Подскажите пожалуйста программу (желательно, для Ubuntu) в которой можно создать подобный граф.
[image: Граф]

Comment: http://www.graphviz.org/

Comment: [yEd](http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yed_about.html)